In one-to-many tables, jpg images in the physical file do not show in the rdlc file
     protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                string deger = Request.QueryString["bulid"];
                mydataset dataSet = new mydataset();

                // Veritabanı bağlantısı ve sorgu oluşturma
                string connectionString = @"Data Source=DESKTOP-1B3OQRL;Initial Catalog=ibroz;Integrated Security=True";

                // SqlConnection, SqlDataAdapter ve DataTable kullanarak veritabanından veri alabilirsiniz
                using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
                {
                    // Veritabanından veri çekme
                    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT urun.*, resim.* FROM urun INNER JOIN resim ON urun.id = resim.urunid WHERE urun.id = @id", connection);
                    da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", deger);

                    // "urun" ve "resim" tablolarını ayrı ayrı doldurma
                    DataTable urunTable = new DataTable("urun");
                    DataTable resimTable = new DataTable("resim");
                    da.Fill(urunTable);
                    da.Fill(resimTable);

                    // DataSet'e tabloları ekleme
                    dataSet.Tables.Add(urunTable);
                    dataSet.Tables.Add(resimTable);

                    // Toplam uygun kayıt sayısını başlatma
                    int uygunKayitSayisi = 0;
                    //string resimYolu = string.Empty; // Her ürün için yeni bir resim yolu başlatılıyor
                    // Her bir resim için işlem yapma
                    foreach (DataRow row in dataSet.Tables["resim"].Rows)
                    {
                        // Resim bilgilerini al
                        string urunid = row["urunid"].ToString();

                        //string resimYolu = "resimler/" + row["buyukyol"].ToString(); // Resimler klasörünü düzeltme
                        string resimYolutek = row["buyukyol"].ToString(); // Resimler klasörünü düzeltme
                        //resimYolu += resimYolutek + ";"; // Her bir resim yolu ekleme işleminde resimYolu değişkenine ekleniyor
                        //                                 // Eğer resmin urunid'si belirtilen değere eşitse işlem yap
                        if (urunid == deger)
                        {
                            // Her bir uygun kayıt için pop-up mesajını göster
                            string script = "alert('ID: " + row["id"] + ", UrunID: " + urunid + ", BuyukYol: " + resimYolutek + "');";
                            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "popup" + urunid + Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), script, true);

                            // Resmi ekrana göster
                            string resimScript = "<script>var resim = new Image(); resim.src = '" + resimYolutek + "'; document.body.appendChild(resim);</script>";
                            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "resim" + urunid + Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), resimScript, false);

                            // Her bir uygun kayıt için uygun kayıt sayısını arttır
                            uygunKayitSayisi++;
                            // Veri kaynaklarını rapora ekleme (sadece resim tablosunu kullanıyoruz)

                        }

                        //row["buyukyol"] = resimYolutek;
                    }


                    //Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.Replace(Request.Url.AbsolutePath, "") + @"~/ImgUpload/"));

                    // Toplam uygun kayıt sayısını bildiren mesajı göster
                    string mesaj = "alert('Toplam " + uygunKayitSayisi + " kayıt bulundu.');";
                    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "kayitBilgilendirme" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), mesaj, true);
                }

                ReportViewer1.ProcessingMode = Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ProcessingMode.Local;
                ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = Server.MapPath("report1.rdlc");
                ReportViewer1.LocalReport.EnableExternalImages = true;
                ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("urun", dataSet.Tables["urun"]));
                ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("resim", dataSet.Tables["resim"]));


                ReportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh();
            }
        }

When the code runs report1.rdlc, the data sources of the image element in the list element are external dir. If this image is ="file://" & Fields!buyukyol.Value, I wrote it this way and as a result, the image path of the last data was displayed in all records, in short, it showed this to all of them. If I write = Fields!buyukyol.Value nothing comes but other information comes correct according to the query.Everything seems normal except for the images. For an id, it brings up normal web page records and images just fine. The problem is that I thought the foreach structure here did not reflect the contents to reportview correctly. Also, it seems like reportview should receive expressions like new quid.
